# Give an example of using GAN models on keras where no images are generated

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Give an example of using GAN models on keras where no images are generated. I want to make GAN music on keras but I don't know how to do it

I wrote GAN to generate images of handwritten digits.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should define what you mean by music:

Do you mean some lyrics for the song, do you mean the musical notes or some actual sound output?  I do not know much about the last example.  But the first two, lyrics and musical notes are a discrete sequence generation problem and it is quite challenging to solve these. I know some example where people combined recurrent neural networks with reinforcement learning techniques. I think you should look into these papers:

This paper uses a GAN with reinforcement learning methods to generate text (code included):

> SeqGAN: Sequence Generative Adversarial Nets with Policy Gradient
> https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05473

The AlphaZero paper is for sure helpful to read about reinforcement learning techniques

> Mastering Chess and Shogi by Self-Play with a General Reinforcement
> Learning Algorithm
> https://paperswithcode.com/paper/mastering-chess-and-shogi-by-self-play-with-a

Text to speech GAN (code included)

> Multi-band MelGAN: Faster Waveform Generation for High-Quality
> Text-to-Speech https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.05106v1

I know, that this is probably not the exact answer you wished for.  But the generation you want to achieve is quite advanced and you should know from the start, what you actually want to perform. There is also the question of the input: Do you want to generate music from a text, do you want to just generate the sound, starting form random? And there are many more possibilities. You should refine your question first or the target you want to reach and then ask again. Otherwise others can just point to literature examples without a clear idea.